# Google App Engine Flexible - routing to specific service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to route to specific service in Google App Engine Flexible without creating a `dispatch.yaml`?

The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-requests-are-routed#default_routing) says we can route to a specific service by calling `http://SERVICE_ID.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`.

When I tried `http://SERVICE_ID.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` it did not work. The request got routed to default and not the service.

So I tried `dispatch.yaml` and it worked.

```
dispatch:
  - url: "SERVICE_ID.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN/*"
    service: SERVICE_ID
```

Sending request to a service is default routing and it should have routed to the service (but did not work?). Why do we need `dispatch.yaml` file in this case?

Comment: Do you specify the subdomain in the GAE custom domain config?

Comment: @Jofre: Yes , i specified the subdomain in the custom domains.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify a subdomain, it'll always point to the default service of your GAE.

To be able to route to each service using subdomains, you must use a [wildcard mapping](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains).

Comment: where do i set the wild card mapping? Is it in when i add a new custom domain? should i put *.SERVICE_ID.MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN in the subdomain field?

Comment: No. In step 2 of the GAE settings while adding a custom domain, when it asks for `The following domain and subdomains will be mapped:`, you must enter `*.example.com`. With this config, when visiting `service-id.example.com` you'll be routed to the service `service-id`. If you use `*.service-id.example.com` you'll be routed to the `default` service when visiting `service-id.example.com`, and to access the service `service-id` you must use a further level of subdomain (the one matching the wildcard): `service-id.service-id.example.com`. After the config is done, update the DNS accordingly.